# How to use with 'pic_crop' in /fql/profile/ API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, crop

I want to use the pic_crop  object of Profile in Facebook query language as listed in this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile/
I activated this on my profile picture and got these results:

```
<fql_query_response list="true">
  <profile>
    <pic_crop>
      <uri>https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/xxxxxx_xxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx_n.jpg</uri>
      <width>180</width>
      <height>173</height>
      <left>0.08468</left>
      <top>0.06897</top>
      <right>0.91532</right>
      <bottom>0.93103</bottom>
    </pic_crop>
  </profile>
</fql_query_response>
```

The width and the height are the sizes of the square in the big picture. Correct me if I'm wrong but I understand that the `top left` and `bottom right` are coordinates in the original big picture to locate correctly the square. I don’t understand exactly what kind of coordinates these are. How with the information of `<left>0.08468</left>` `<top>0.06897</top>` I can get to the top-left pixel in the big picture to crop the square? By the way I'm writing in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

the left, top, right, bottom are the ratio, not absolute position.

```
x = width * left = 15.2424
y = height * top = 11.93181
sw = width * (right-left) = 149.5152
sh = height * (bottom -top ) = 149.13638
```

where sw,sh is the width and height of the square.